# Incorrect color of UITabBar and UINavigationBar

Tags: swift

I have a problem with working UITabBar and UINavigationBar (they are turning grey after changing screen orientation). I tried to reproduce this problem on the devices and have got the same result as I got with Xcode emulator: if I try to change screen orientation to landscape mode after opening my app, I have wrong color (grey) of UINavigationBar and UITabBar. Also if I open my app while screen orientation is in landscape mode, this problem can’t be seen.

So..I have found one worse way of fixing for me: if I set to barTintColor in UIToolbar not nil value, the problem is fixed, but there is no blur effect which I want.

I didn`t find any solution of this problem. Help me, please, if you can. Thanks

Comment: Maybe showing the relevant code?

Comment: @Magnas , do you mean this? https://dropmefiles.com.ua/ru/KRA2zsXQ93